# Bluetooth LE 'onConnectionStateChange' will not called after 'connectGatt'

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a project with Bluetooth LE on Android-Studios in Java.
Unfortunately I'm stucked on the process between connectGatt() <-> onConnectionStateChange().
After each onScanResult I try to connect to the found device: [Logcat-Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuHzs.png). This happens ~20 times repeatly, without that 'onConnectionStateChange' will called. After that it closes all connections automatically, probably by Android, because of to much connections 'onConnectionStateChange' (because of 'disconnect') will called.

'connectGatt' calls 'connect', but doesn't call, whyever, 'onConnectionStateChange' - so I guess the issue is 'connectGatt'.

**Simple Pseudo Code of my problem:**

```
btLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback);

public class BtLeScanCallback extends ScanCallback {
    @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
            BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, autoConnect, callback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
        }
   
public class BtGattCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionState: " + newState);

        switch (newState){
            case STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.i(TAG, "State connected.");
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.i(TAG, "State disconnected.");
                gatt.close();
                break;
            }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea? :D
I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can only connect to one device at a time. So stop scanning when you find a device and then connect. Then wait for the connection to complete. After that you can start scanning for more devices.

Comment: I thought I can be connected to up to 6 devices at the same time?
According to my code, a connection to the device is established as soon as it is found. I am notified of this in the callback. As soon as this has happened, 'discoverServices ()' is called and the connection is closed in its callback after it has expired (disconnect & close).
Therefore it should never have more than 6 simultaneous connections anyway.

But yes, in itself an orderly search could solve the problem, since I am connecting in a wild way through the opposite. ^^

Comment: But one question: so I'm able to start the scan again after onConnectionState was called or have I wait until all possible callback was called?

Comment: [EDIT] Nope, didn't fix my problem. I have now tried it so that it ends the search after the 1st device. But still no callback was called. o.O.